# Insert retrieved data of image paths via json jquery and insert in img tag src

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

i m grabbing image paths from MySQL via php and then json_encode and with response data i m using below code to display image but not working

My PHP Code

```
$imgurl=array();
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
//Fetch rows
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$imgurl = $row['imgurl'];  
}
}
echo json_encode($imgurl);  
else
{
echo "No results matching family \"$family\"";
}
```

The Code at my Jquery side

```
success: function( data ){
$('#pgwrapid').html(data);
}
```

the data is giving below output which are actually image paths

```
 ["images\/zara\/shoes\/thumbnail","images\/hermes\/shoes\/thumbnail","images\/hermes\/shoes\/thumbnail"]
```

now how to remove the backslashes and insert it in img src=""

Comment: What do you mean "giving a bunch of t"?  Do you mean the image src is being set to "ttttttttttt"?  What happens if you display the value of `val` in a console or alert?  Maybe the issue is that the wrong data is being returned?

Comment: I edited my code completely not even at the console is it printing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below :

```
   success: function( data ){

             $.each(data,function(index,val){
                $('#pgwrapid').append("<img src='"+val+"' alt='Thumbnail'/>");


                }); 
            }
```

But please check first if you are getting value in `val` or not.

Comment: again printing a series of thumbnail

Comment: $.each is ok here ? function  used to iterate over any collection. I am not getting exactly what you want to do  If there is single image is to append then why used each there ? is it repeating same thambnail over and over ?

Comment: I edited my code completely not even at the console is it printing something there re a bunch of images yes it is repeating it over and over

Comment: $.each(data, function(index, value) { 
  alert(index + ': ' + value); 
});   just check what's output

Comment: its printing anonymous values

Comment: so something is wrong with "data" format. Can you please paste what you getting in data here ?

Comment: see check this link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ . you need to pass data in whether it is a (JavaScript object) or an array. In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each time. so format your data correctly. It will work

Comment: done but its givung me this output    ["images\/zara\/shoes\/thumbnail","images\/hermes\/shoes\/thumbnail","images\/hermes\/shoes\/thumbnail","images\/hermes\/shoes\/thumbnail"]  i dont need the back slash

Comment: Check in database it they are comming from database query and if you want to remove them you'll need to process the string returned from the DB before you return or json_encode()

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong quotes there. You need to use single quotes for `alt='Thumbnail'` or escape the double quotes you are already using `alt=\"Thumbnail\"`

Comment: I edited my code completely not even at the console is it printing something

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
success: function( data ){
var evaluateddata = eval('('+data+')');

$.each(evaluateddata,function(index,val){
   $('#pgwrapid').append("<img src="+val+" alt="Thumbnail"/>");
 });
}
```

the data is treated as a string after the request, but when it comes json I love to use the hard coded iterative way in javascript (not really fund of using .each() api of jquery so I have a doubt on the above code though not sure if it should be val or should I still identify the variable to access such as `val.<variablename>`) like this:

```
success: function( data ){
    var evaluateddata = eval('('+data+')');

    for(val in evaluateddata)
    {
       $('#pgwrapid').append("<img src="+evaluateddata[val]+" alt="Thumbnail"/>");
    }
}
```

this is the direct javascript approach to iterate on the json object but it depends on you which one is ideal for you (somehow it would be better if you post the original json string response from your application).

I see the code. how about if you try this code:

```
 if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
    //Fetch rows
    $output = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $output[] = $row['imgurl'];
       }
    echo json_encode($output);
}else{
    echo "No results matching family \"$family\"";
}
```

your code is actually trying to output a separate json value for each imgurl definitely it won't work because the json value that your application will be returning would be evaluated as one and your code is printing several json values which may cause errors when your javascript code receives it.

Comment: I edited my code completely not even at the console is it printing something